# Flatten nested JSON with jq

Tags: json, jq

I'm trying to flatten some nested JSON with jq. My first attempt was by looping over the JSON in bash with base64 [as per this article](https://starkandwayne.com/blog/bash-for-loop-over-json-array-using-jq/). It turned out to perform very slowly, so I'm trying to figure out an alternative with just jq.

I have some JSON like this:

```
[
  {
    "id":117739,
    "officers": "[{\"name\":\"Alice\"},{\"name\":\"Bob\"}]"
  },
  {
    "id":117740,
    "officers":"[{\"name\":\"Charlie\"}]"
  }
]
```

The `officers` field holds a string which is JSON too. I'd like to reduce this to:

```
[
  { "id":117739, "name":"Alice" },
  { "id":117739, "name":"Bob" },
  { "id":117740, "name":"Charlie" }
]
```

Comment: By the way, regarding that article, please note that using base64 to achieve iteration in bash is never necessary because compact JSON provides the necessary encoding itself. For example, using `IFS= read -r` does the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the data you're attempting to flatten is itself JSON so you have to parse it using `fromjson`. Once parsed, you could then generate the new objects.

```
map({id} + (.officers | fromjson[]))
```