# How tabulize nested JSON lists using jq in bash

Tags: json, bash, jq, export-to-csv, nested-lists

I would like to parse data from a JSON-file into a tsv-file, but I cannot make it work.

## Input

```
{
  "images": [
    {
      "id": "592a77a5-614e-4ed8-b846-d4db1f27edbf",
      "name": "ubuntu",
      "tags": [
        "latest"
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "592da7a5-614e-4ed8-b846-d4db1f27edbf",
      "name": "debian",
      "tags": [
        "latest",
        "10.0"
      ]
    }   
  ]
}
```

## Desired output

The desired output is a tab-separated table

```
ubuntu    latest
debian    latest
debian    10.0
```

## What I have tried

```
# My data
echo '{"images":[{"id":"592a77a5-614e-4ed8-b846-d4db1f27edbf","name":"ubuntu","tags":["latest"]},{"id":"592da7a5-614e-4ed8-b846-d4db1f27edbf","name":"debian","tags":["latest","10.0"]}]}' > my.json

# My query
jq -r '.images | map({id} + (.tags | fromjson[])) | @tsv' my.json > my.tsv
```

First I access the images-list, then I want to make an operation over all ids, where I want the tags. I borrowed the map from a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52614115/flatten-nested-json-with-jq), but it does not seem to work. The only difference between my query and theirs is the extra layer with the **.images**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the name into a variable before you go down to the tags

```sh
jq -r '.images[] | .name as $name | .tags[] | [$name, .] | @tsv'
```

```json
ubuntu  latest
debian  latest
debian  10.0
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/6oTmSM1jp5n)